# Open Source Music Player able to play whole-album FLAC with cue

Tags: linux, open-source, media-player, flac

Is there an open source media player (that runs on Linux) that can play a whole-album FLAC presented as multiple tracks rather than one track ?

There are many players (I usually use VLC and Audacious) but the neither recognise embedded cue data nor separate cue file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/)

supports CUE sheets since version 0.7 (2011).

Comment: Interesting, it looks nice. A quick test shows that it works with a cue file but does not use the cue data embedded in the flac file. (ie. playing the cue file works as expected but playing the flac directly yields one track). What would be nice is if it used the flac's cue data with a query to a db (freedb/musicbrainz) to get the track data (the embeeded cue only contains track positions). But Clementine definately looks worth getting to know... Time to move on from Audacious...

Comment: I found a tracked issue for embedded cue support: https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/1276